# FREEBSD creating new port

Tags: freebsd

I have a script here that I want to create as a port in freebsd and then make it as package so that I can install on some machines. script is below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "/suid.old" ]
then
find / -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 -ls > /suid.old
else
find / -perm -4000 -o -perm -2000 -ls > /suid.new
diff suid.old suid.new > newchanges
fi
exit 0
if [ -s "/newchanges" ]
then
  mail -s "changes has occured" someone@gmail.com
else
  mail -s "No changes has occured" someone@gmail.com /newchanges
fi
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only installing that one small script, I'd just do it manually. You could use a `shar` file, but that seems like overkill.

The biggest issues I see are first, that `bash` is going to be located in different locations on different systems, but there's nothing in your script that's Bash-specific, so you could change your shebang to:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

for portability.

Second, you will need to choose a location for your script. It strikes me that `/usr/local/bin` would be as good as any.

Third, you will need to `chown` to set the ownership and `chmod` to set the permissions.

Fourth, you should choose better locations for your output files. If they are only for temporary use, then they should be created in `/tmp` rather than the root directory where you have `suid.old` and `suid.new` going, or the current directory where you have `newchanges` going. Otherwise, somewhere in `var` might be where you'd want to put more persistent data. Perhaps `/var/local/suid`.

Fifth, the `exit` prevents the second `if` from ever being evaluated so no mail will ever be sent.

Sixth, you might want to `mv suid.new suid.old` at some point so the next time you do your check it's comparing the most recent saved data.

Seventh, your last mail command should have the file piped or redirected in. It won't work as an argument. And the two mail commands should be swapped so you're not mailing a file when it's empty and are mailing it when it's not.

```
if [ -s "/newchanges" ]
then
  mail -s "No changes have occurred" someone@gmail.com < /path/to/newchanges
else
  mail -s "changes have occurred" someone@gmail.com
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A port for one shell script is beyond overkill -- As Dennis said this is something I would copy to individual machines as needed (or create a package manually, but this is a pain).

I'm also not sure this has sufficient general utility to make it into the official ports collection (in particular, there is already a "setuid binaries" check as part of the daily security audit).

All that said, details on creating a port can be found [in the Porter's Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/), and you can always roll a local port just for your site.